# Getting Configuration Strings For Http Client

Tags: c#, http, configuration, client

I have five different HttpPost methods. Each one gets a client from the same end point. For this reason, I am repeating the code where I get the section, uri and endpoint values for the configuration.

I thought of getting these values with a method to simplify the code. But I can't decide on the return type of the method. Is there a special return type for this case?

```
public ? GetReportConfig(string sectionName, string host, string endpoint)
    {
        var section = this._configuration.GetSection(sectionName);
        string uriString = section.GetValue<string>(host);
        string endpointString = section.GetValue<string>(endpoint);

    }
```

Comment: You can always make your custom class, struct (or recently: record) or use a tuple ( `(string,string)` ).

Comment: Your controller is returning [Get] different IActionResults.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @Fildor thx, I didn't know the tuple, I tried and it works.